# What is length of axis in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am just starting up with numpy. The [quick start tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) says:

> The coordinates of a point in 3D space [1, 2, 1] has one axis. That axis has 3 elements in it, so we say it has a length of 3. In the example pictured below, the array has 2 axes. The first axis has a length of 2, the second axis has a length of 3.
>
> ```
> [[ 1., 0., 0.],  
>  [ 0., 1., 2.]]
> ```

I am not getting "The first axis has a length of 2, the second axis has a length of 3." I can see both `[ 1., 0., 0.]` and `[ 0., 1., 2.]` containing three elements, then why their length is not 3?

Comment: len of Numpy array returns length of 1st dimension bcoz underlying `__ len __` function may be implemented like that.  Use `*givenarray*.shape` to get dimensions of Numpy array

Comment: think like 2 rows as (1'st axis) and 3 columns as (2'nd axis).

Comment: You're looking at the rows when you should be looking at the axes.

Comment: How much have you learned about matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you show is not bad, but it is confusing you. The term "axis" is equivalent to "dimension". Take this array:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6]]
```

This array is two-dimensional. The fact that the first dimension, or axis, has two elements is just a coincidence. The axes are *not* `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6]`.

A less confusing example may be the following:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [4, 5, 6]]
```

This array is also two-dimensional, but it has 4 elements in the first dimension. The shape is `(4, 3)`: 4 rows, 3 columns in each row.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a 2-D matrix of dimensions NxM. This means that it has N rows and M columns. And when represented graphically, this matrix would have 2 axes horizontal(against which column indexes are marked) and vertical(against which the row indexes are marked).

Taking the concept here, the array shown here is a 2-D array(an array of some arrays) so, it has 2 axes.

- Number of rows = 2 = first axis length.
- Number of columns = 3 = second axis length.